How do I compute nearby public transportation departures (Like TransitApp home screen) using GTFS & PostgreSQL?
I am trying to replicate something like this found in the Transit App: Basically a list of nearby departures, and it shows the next couple departures for both directions within a certain radius of the user or input point.
I have a global set of GTFS feeds (thousands) in my postgres database.
To sort it, I usually store everything with the agency id and then something else to form the primary key, such as (paris, route_1) as a route. I put all the stops into an r-tree, and so are all the shapes.
All the timetables are over 500GB so I had to compress it down to 100 GB like this:
I check each stop time's offset from the trip start. I store itineraries which is like [A:0, B:60, C:500, D: 900], number of seconds since start. Then I start the trip id with the start time. I have an index on the itineraries on stop rows, and I store the metadata for each itinerary in a seperate table.
This usually results in a compression ratio from 4 to 12 depending on agency. I've also made a set of directions which is just unique stop id lists like [A, B, C, D] and [D, C, B, A] along with the average time since the start, but this is only meant for the route information screen, not for this algorithm. Metadata is also in a seperate table.
I also have to account for cancelled stops in my algorithm using the realtime data that will skip the stop and advance to the next closest stop. I have a system that stores my realtime data on a cluster of RPC servers and I've made some "indicies" on it.
Here's the code if you're interested https://github.com/catenarytransit/catenary-backend, I am using diesel as my ORM but I can also do raw queries and filters.
To try to find nearby departures, I am doing a radius search from a point up to 1km (or 2km for sparce areas) then doing a join with the itineraries. I can sort the stops by distance, put the itineraries into a hashmap by stop id and then start to eliminate itineraries (routes) one by one until there are none left. The problem is that if I try to query chicago or manhatten, the r-tree returns results very quickly (about 900 stops), but then the actual itinerary_pattern search returns over 400 000 results. The directions are a bit better at 14 000 rows but I still then have to query all the itinerary pattern metadata that match the directions and then query all the itinerary rows matching the itinerary patterns. This query alone takes over 20 seconds on my postgres server, which is fast for other queries.
I understand I also have to unwravel the time offsets but I already know how to do that.
I might have to switch my database structure as well to handle this problem.

Interesting, but way to wide subject for a SO question.

@jarlh how is it too wide? Your comment doesn't make any sense, there's clearly a history of people asking questions related to GTFS querying like routing algorithms on stack overflow.
